# Как отобразить файл в память (CreateFileMapping),чтобы изменения не сохранились в файле?

Tags: c++, c

Отображаю файл в память:

```
hMapObject = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READWRITE, 0, 0, NULL);
lpBase = MapViewOfFile(hMapObject, FILE_MAP_READ|FILE_MAP_WRITE, 0, 0, 0);
```

Затем мне нужно совершить некоторые операции(модификация) над отображаемой информацией в памяти. При этом я не хочу, чтобы эти изменения перенеслись на файл на диске. Как мне быть? Думаю над тем, чтобы скопировать отображаемую информацию в другую область памяти и там совершать изменения, но пока не понимаю в какую область памяти мне можно скопировать информацию

Comment: По идее, на файл должны накладываться только простые структуры без указателей и локальных дескрипторов. В таком случае ничего не мешает копировать отображенный на файл массив при помощи `memcpy` в любое место и модифицировать данные там. В чем именно у вас проблема? Размер файла известен (`GetFileSize`, по крайней мере если файл до 4 ГБ), можно выделять память под скопированный массив динамически.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, в механизме работы отображения файлов на память предусмотрен и Ваш случай. В вызове `MapViewOfFile()` нужно использовать параметр `FILE_MAP_COPY` - он будет создавать копии измененных страниц памяти в адресном пространстве Вашего процесса. При этом, само отображение (как объект ядра) можно создавать с атрибутом `PAGE_WRITECOPY`. *Но это не точно* :-) . 
В том смысле, что так сделано в примере в книге: *Рихтер  Дж.* "Windows для профессионалов: создание эффективных Win32-приложений с учетом  специфики  64-разрядной  версии  Windows"  /  Пер.  с  англ.  —  4-е  изд.  —  Спб.:  Питер;  М.:  Издательство  «Русская  Редакция»;  2008.  —  720  стр.:  ил. (стр. 428 о работе с файлами, отображаемыми на память).

Сам же я открывал файл и отображение - только на чтение. Вроде, бы все работает и так (у меня был текстовый файл и с него надо было многократно извлекать данные, и соответственно, я работал с ним как с обычной си-строкой. А чтобы она стала "строкой", в отображении нужно было подменять последний символ на '\0').

В итоге:

```
hFile = CreateFile(filename, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_READONLY|FILE_FLAG_RANDOM_ACCESS, 0);
hMap  = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, 0, 0, NULL);
mapwnd = MapViewOfFile(hMap, FILE_MAP_COPY, 0, 0, 0); // если нужно отобразить файл целиком
// здесь обрабатываем отображенный файл
UnmapViewOfFile(mapwnd);
```

Либо как у Рихтера в книге:

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(pszFileName, GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
HANDLE hFileMapping = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_WRITECOPY, 0, 0, NULL);
PBYTE pbFile = (PBYTE) MapViewOfFile(hFileMapping, FILE_MAP_COPY, 0, 0, 0);
// здесь у Рихтера что-то изменяется в pbFile
UnmapViewOfFile(pbFile);
```

В комментариях к примеру он пишет, что все измененные данные будут потеряны при закрытии отображения.

Естественно, на каждом этапе нужно обрабатывать возвращаемые ошибки, а после работы - закрывать все дескрипторы. Я эту часть кода опустил.